# How to arbitrarily label the points in ListPointPlot3D within Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d

I want to label the points displayed in 3D within a `Manipulate` expression  with arbitrary text. My code is as follows:

```
data2 = {{0.000, 0.000, 0.000}, {-1.612, 8.077, -2.474}, {-19.599, 
186.849, -246.583}, {-29.000, -19.499, 
12.157}, {-1.646, -1.375, -3.842}, {3.127, -19.235, 
15.660}, {167.744, 834.512, -122.686}, {-5.353 , 9.547, 
1.096}, {13.369, 634.519, 82.506}, {36.150, 235.772, 
26.543}, {5.481, 28.657, 30.211}, {22.354, 58.173, 
18.471}, {-206.890, -495.847, -267.081}, {-13.242 , 26.759, 
16.267}, {-17.712 , 40.444, 27.470}, {-66.567, 35.256, 
15.966}, {-1224.806, 
3234.005, -1669.329}, {-1.546, -1.183, -3.769}, {-0.057, -5.943, 
0.488}, {-7.430 , 2.113, 0.950}, {-6.506 , 1.642, 
4.870}, {1.910, -8.647, -3.912}, {6.213, 8.314, -1.729}, {10.287, 
5.021, -3.269}, {6.468, -2.746, 
11.114}, {14.243, -4.268, -3.780}, {-24.260 , 25.880, 
19.125}, {-24.952, -8.886, -8.766}, {45.832, -12.825, 
18.049}, {7.807, -14.872, 2.621}, {68.981, 
31.332, -117.728}, {20.933, -5.840, -12.357}, {-237.661, -92.652,
-50.329}, {4.354, 3.396, 429.965}, {1184.687, -1394.076, 
1847.449}, {47.862, 51.402, 
60.959}, {-172.829, -36.515, -302.153}, {4.898, -32.843, 42.075}};

text2 = Graphics3D[{Blue, 
Map[Style[Text[Sequence @@ #], Bold] &, 
 Transpose[{{"Sun", "Sirius", "Canopus", "Arcturus", "Rigil K", 
    "Vega", "Rigel", "Procyon", "Betelgeuse", "Bellatrix", 
    "Capella", "Aldebaran", "Antares", "Pollux", "Castor", 
    "Regulus", "VY Canis M", "Proxima C", "Barnard", "Wolf 359", 
    "Lalande 21185", "Ross 154", "Epsilon Eri", "Tau Ceti", 
    "Kruger 60", "Gliese 876", "55 Cancri", "61 Virginis", 
    "51 Pegasi", "Altair", "Achernar", "Fomalhaut", "Spica", 
    "Polaris", "Deneb", "Algol", "Mimosa", "BY Draconis"}, 
   data2}]]}];

Show[ListPointPlot3D[data2,PlotRange -> {{-4000, 4000}, {-4000, 4000}, {-4000, 4000}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z},   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ImageSize -> {700},   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]]], text2]

Manipulate[ListPointPlot3D[data2, PlotRange -> {{-n, n}, {-n, n}, {-n, n}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ImageSize -> {700},    PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]]], {n, 1, 4000}];
```

Comment: Look up `Text[]` or `Inset[]`.

Comment: What you have works if you take the `Show` and stick in in `Manipulate` replacing the `PlotRange` with `PlotRange -> {{-n, n}, {-n, n}, {-n, n}}`. However, the plot jumps around in size (frankly, I don't understand why).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this solution, which uses [`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html), will work for you. I prefer this approach because it is simple and minimizes clutter in the plot.

```
data = 
  {{0.000, 0.000, 0.000}, {-1.612, 8.077, -2.474}, {-19.599, 186.849, -246.583}, 
   {-29.000, -19.499, 12.157}, {-1.646, -1.375, -3.842}, {3.127, -19.235, 15.660}, 
   {167.744, 834.512, -122.686}, {-5.353, 9.547, 1.096}, {13.369, 634.519, 82.506}, 
   {36.150, 235.772, 26.543}, {5.481, 28.657, 30.211}, {22.354, 58.173, 18.471}, 
   {-206.890, -495.847, -267.081}, {-13.242, 26.759, 16.267}, 
   {-17.712, 40.444, 27.470}, {-66.567, 35.256, 15.966}, 
   {-1224.806, 3234.005, -1669.329}, {-1.546, -1.183, -3.769}, 
   {-0.057, -5.943, 0.488}, {-7.430, 2.113, 0.950}, {-6.506, 1.642, 4.870}, 
   {1.910, -8.647, -3.912}, {6.213, 8.314, -1.729}, {10.287, 5.021, -3.269}, 
   {6.468, -2.746, 11.114}, {14.243, -4.268, -3.780}, {-24.260, 25.880, 19.125}, 
   {-24.952, -8.886, -8.766}, {45.832, -12.825, 18.049}, {7.807, -14.872, 2.621}, 
   {68.981, 31.332, -117.728}, {20.933, -5.840, -12.357}, 
   {-237.661, -92.652, -50.329}, {4.354, 3.396, 429.965}, 
   {1184.687, -1394.076, 1847.449}, {47.862, 51.402, 60.959}, 
   {-172.829, -36.515, -302.153}, {4.898, -32.843, 42.075}};

names = 
  {"Sun", "Sirius", "Canopus", "Arcturus", "Rigil K", "Vega", 
   "Rigel", "Procyon", "Betelgeuse", "Bellatrix", "Capella", 
   "Aldebaran", "Antares", "Pollux", "Castor", "Regulus", 
   "VY Canis M", "Proxima C", "Barnard", "Wolf 359", "Lalande 21185", 
   "Ross 154", "Epsilon Eri", "Tau Ceti", "Kruger 60", "Gliese 876", 
   "55 Cancri", "61 Virginis", "51 Pegasi", "Altair", "Achernar", 
   "Fomalhaut", "Spica", "Polaris", "Deneb", "Algol", "Mimosa", 
   "BY Draconis"};

Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
    {Blue, PointSize[Large], MapThread[Tooltip[Point@#1, #2] &, {data2, names}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-n, n}, {-n, n}, {-n, n}},
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
    Axes -> True,
    AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z},
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold]],
  {n, 50, 3500, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: stars]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying! I think i will go along your method. However i need to add a circle in the 3d box which has four points in degrees: 0, 90, 180 and 270? Can you help please? Thanks

Comment: @VickramRatnam. You should ask about your circle in a new question. When you do, please make it clear how you want the 2D circle to be placed in a 3D plot -- it is not a trivial matter.

Answer (score 2):

```
labels = {"Sun", "Sirius", "Canopus", "Arcturus", "Rigil K", "Vega", 
   "Rigel", "Procyon", "Betelgeuse", "Bellatrix", "Capella", 
   "Aldebaran", "Antares", "Pollux", "Castor", "Regulus", 
   "VY Canis M", "Proxima C", "Barnard", "Wolf 359", "Lalande 21185", 
   "Ross 154", "Epsilon Eri", "Tau Ceti", "Kruger 60", "Gliese 876", 
   "55 Cancri", "61 Virginis", "51 Pegasi", "Altair", "Achernar", 
   "Fomalhaut", "Spica", "Polaris", "Deneb", "Algol", "Mimosa", "BY Draconis"};
```

Using `BubbleChart3D` and its `ChartLabels` option:

```
Manipulate[BubbleChart3D[Pick[{##, 1} & @@@ data2, 
                              And[-n <= # <= n, -n <= #2 <= n, -n <= #3 <= n]& @@@ data2], 
  ChartStyle -> 1, ChartLabels ->labels, 
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#3[[2, 1]], Tooltip] &), 
  PlotRange -> {{-n, n}, {-n, n}, {-n, n}}], {n, 1, 4000}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use `ChartLabels -> Placed[labels, None]` to get:
[image: Mathematica graphics]